# Show user roles in HTML page without bracket

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring security to authenticate user in my web page. I would like to show for each user his roles without bracket.
If I use

```
<p sec:authentication='principal.authorities'></p>
```

I see [ADMIN, USER].
Is there a way in thymeleaf, javascript or HTML to show only ADMIN,USER?
I know that in thymeleaf there is spring replace but how can I pass the result of above code?
Thanks, regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity) provides access to an `#authentication` object which can return the list of GrantedAuthorities. There will be a GrantedAuthority for each role assigned (prefixed by 'ROLE_').

You can use this to loop through and display each role (removing the ROLE_ prefix):

```
    <p th:each="authority : ${#authentication.getAuthorities()}"
       th:if="${authority.getAuthority().startsWith('ROLE_')}"
       th:text="${authority.getAuthority().replaceFirst('ROLE_', '')}">
    </p>
```

Comment: if I store in database the role without "ROLE_" I might have problems?

Comment: @luca I might be mistaken, but I think spring-security automatically adds the ROLE_

Comment: at this time I am using ADMIN and USER without problem. With this code:
<p th:each="authority : ${#authentication.getAuthorities()}" th:text="${authority.getAuthority()}"> it returns all the roles. The only problems is that show elements in different <p> tag and not on the same line

Comment: @luca well that's simple to solve. You can use a `th:block` which doesn't result in any output in the generated html, and use the `iterStat` to add commas (apart from the last one): `<p><th:block th:each="authority, iterStat : ${#authentication.getAuthorities()}"><th:block th:text="${authority.getAuthority() + (iterStat.last?'':',')}"></th:block></th:block></p>`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, late to this thread, but here is a working solution using Thymeleaf and [Thymeleaf Extras](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity)

```
Role(s):
<th:block th:each="r, iter:${#authentication.getAuthorities()}">
    <span th:text="${r}"></span>
    <th:block th:if="${!iter.last}">, </th:block>
</th:block>
```

The code above will add a comma except after the last role.

Answer (score 0):

I think you see the brackets because 'principal.authorities' is an array. Try with the jstl taglib.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:forEach var="item" items="principal.authorities">
   <c:out value="${item}"/>
</c:forEach>
...
```

Comment: yes, I see the brackets because the result is an array. is there no way to avoid jstl? I'm not using it  in my project

Comment: If you're using Thymeleaf, you can use the `th:each` attribute.

Example : 
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
...
<p th:each="item : ${principal.authorities}"></p>`

(From Thymeleaf manual)
[link](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html)

Comment: the variable is returned through sec:authentication='principal.authorities' and if I iterato on this I receive error

Comment: Try declaring the variable this way: 
`<sec:authentication property="authorities" var="auth" />`

and then using it with _th:each_ :
`<div th:each="item : ${auth}">
          item.authority
</div>`

Comment: I made a mistake in the answer, try replacing
`<sec:authentication property="authorities" var="auth" />`
with
`<sec:authentication property="principal.authorities" var="auth" />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98319/discussion-between-paolo-finamore-and-luca).